# What problems might I miss by debugging a release build instead of debug build?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

Let's say I prefer debugging a release build of my software during development.

What problems might I miss by doing that?

Comment: title = opposite of question body text?

Comment: Your title and question are opposites.

Comment: Maybe he wrote one in debug... how meta!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may miss buffer overruns.   The debug code adds padding around the memory available to your program, the release build does not.    So the debugger can detect and warn when you write unowned memory in the debug build.   In the release build the same problem may go unnoticed until the user enters that one special input that crashes everything.

The same is true of using uninitialized variables.   The debug build detects it, the release build will not.   And it's Murphy's Law that the last change before release will change the uninitialized variable to something that causes problems with the section you decided not to retest.

Comment: This actually applies mostly to C / C++, not sure how C# differs here.

Answer (score 5):

1. There are some optimizations that take place in the Release build.  You can see the full list of optimizations [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/11/what-does-the-optimize-switch-do.aspx).  None of them are supposed to affect the outcome of the program.
2. If you have the DEBUG directive anywhere, that will stay in.  Pay careful attention to this, as this could change whole functions.
3. Debug.Asserts will fail in Debug mode but NOT in Release mode.

Comment: Huh, I wonder if code that is JIT-ed over a release build is different from code JIT-ed over a Debug build, beyond the optimizations that Eric suggests in this post.

Comment: @cunningdave, Eric Lippert says at at the bottom of that alcohol, that there are huge wins to be done at JIT time in release build.

Comment: Right, that list of optimizations is optimizations performed *on the IL*. The IL isn't what runs, the IL is just the input to the jitter. The jitter knows whether a program was compiled for debug or retail and it knows whether you are debugging it right now or not, and it is the jitter that can decide whether to more heavily optimize the actual running program accordingly.

Comment: @EricLippert, I just noticed my typo.  I wasn't suggesting you'd hit the bottle :)

Comment: @EricLippert: Hmmm... so if I attach a debugger to a release build, will the jitter then produce machine code as if the build was a non-optimized debug build?

Comment: @JohannGerell: No. How could it do that? The jitter doesn't know what IL the C# compiler would generate for a non-optimized build!

Comment: @EricLippert: Ah, damn, I meant **will the jitter then produce machine code as if the build was an *optimized* debug build?** (so that it'll make sense to, say, single step in the debugger without it jumping all over the place?)

Comment: @JohannGerell: You'll have to ask an expert on the jitter if you want to know precisely what it does differently when it detects that a debugger is attached.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the most annoying one is the "non-volatile flag used to signal a thread to stop causes a deadlock in release mode but not in debug mode".

This is encountered often as:

```
flag = false;

Thread t = new Thread(
   o =>
   {
        while(!flag)
        {
           // do stuff
        }
   });
t.Start();

// main thread does some work

flag = true;
t.Join(); // will never return in release mode if flag is not volatile
```

This happens because of compiler optimizations in release mode, as the `flag` variable gets cached by the core of thread `t` and thus it cannot see the updated value of `flag`.

Comment: This is a reason that you _should_ do at least some of your debugging in release mode.

Comment: @AShelly: He actually changed the question, because when I answered it was "what do I miss if I'm using debug instead of release".

Answer (score 3):

In release, there are some optimizations made by the compiler. So maybe there are some variables you won't be able to read or some functions inlined. But globally, you'll be able to point where the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

It's not so much the problems that you might miss when you try to debug a release build, as the things you cannot do or work "strangely":

- Some variables may be optimized away, so you can't inspect them
- properties and/or methods may be inlined so that code position is lost

Answer (score 2):

The predefined debug and release configurations control build parameters such as the DEBUG constant and code optimization.

The code that's debug conditional (#IF DEBUG) will not be executed in release mode. As already said, the optimization may also hide variables.

Another thing that might prevent you to debug correctly is whether the pdb files are generated or not (build/advanced/debug info), if not, VS will not be able to show you the source code of the app you are debugging.